# Swipe Up/Left/Right/Bottom, Float button in android

Tags: android, button, swipe, drag, lockscreen

I'm looking for something like this to use in my apps. What is it called and what /i have to search for? Is anyone know any library that do so?

I want somewhere in my app to swipe from center to up and do rating, swipe right to like, swipe left to call, swipe bottom to cancel

[image: This is what i am looking for]

Comment: I don't know if there is any library solution, but if there is one they created a View and used a View.OnTouchListener or maybe a GestureDetector. There are some guides out there in the www showing how to implement one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this library, you should do some work to make it work like you want, but it's very close to it!

https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/MovingButton

Comment: The question wants a button that can expand by touching it to show more items that can be selected when the user hovers on them with their finger and release, I know ```Moving button``` can work but it's far from what the question wants

Answer (score 1):

### **I think [`MultiChoicesCircleButton`](https://github.com/gjiazhe/MultiChoicesCircleButton) will help**

Here is an [Example Gif](https://github.com/gjiazhe/MultiChoicesCircleButton/blob/master/screenshots/gif1.gif)

---

It's customizable so you can

- Change it's color
- Change distance between items and the center
- Disable the parallax effect if you
  want and lots of more stuff